# Start application on Diego by default while Cloud Foundry uses DEA by default

Tags: cloud-foundry

We have a Cloud Foundry 2 deployment which supports Diego. In our case, the DEA ist still the default and when we push an application, it is used. I can change the application deployment to Diego using the Diego Enabler Plugin to switch to and fro.

Is it possible to somehow tell Cloud Foundry that I would like to deploy the application to Diego, even though it is not the default, in a more automized manner, like by enabling the boolean 'diego' field in the manifest somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently possible to do in-manifest.

I checked with the Diego and CLI teams on the [Cloud Foundry Slack](https://slack.cloudfoundry.org), and they say it can't be done. I think the design rationale is that one shouldn't be running both architectures for a long time, but I can understand how having it in-manifest would be nice.

Comment: Well, that's a pity. Thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Via script you can push --no-start, switch it to Diego, then start it.  Not as nice as manifest but not bad.

Comment: There is one issue - I'm not using the CLI right now, I'm rather using the Cloud Foundry Jenkins plugin. It doesn't have any options for '--no-start', so I would have to call the CLI here. The issue is I need to log in to use the CLI and tell it the org and space to use, but Jenkins will be deploying to different orgs/spaces in different jobs. As the CLI saves login data in user home, parallel jobs will sooner or later break one another by overriding each other's settings. Will have to check if it is possible to override where the CLI saves this information.

Comment: It is possible to set the CF_HOME env and this will define where the CLI saves the login information, should help.